# Angular Input() takes undefined after providing default value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-input

Below is Input decorator used with 3 variables and assigned default values to each variable

```
  @Input() score: number = 0;
  @Input() text: string = 'test';
  @Input() color: string = 'red';
```

This is how I am passing values to the component inside a ngFor.

```
  [text]="item.name"
  [score]="item.score"
  [color]="item.color"
```

If my item object does not contain **color property** then the color variable in the component should take **'red'** as default value.

But when I log it as :

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.score, this.text, this.color);
  }
```

then the color variable takes **undefined** as value.

Here is the console for above logs for

```
8 "English" undefined
6 "Spanish" "blue"
```

The 1st log is when the item **does not** contain **color** property, and 2nd is when it contains property **color** with value **blue**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a `setter` to the input property to determine whether it is a valid value or not and assign it to a default value as

```
private color: string;

@Input('color')
set Color(color: string) {
    this.color = color || 'red';
}
```

A sample created at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setter-for-null-input-property

Comment: Typescript throws @angular-eslint/no-input-rename for this so it doesn't seem like the correct fix.

Comment: Thats linting, not typescript. Your code styles are different then Saksham: just rename as `@Input() set color(color: string)`

Answer (score 1):

The default value means when you are not passing any value, then angular puts the default value. But here you are passing `undefined` (when the property does not exist) and it's pretty obvious that angular puts `undefined` as `color` variable.

You can fix this by putting the default  value into your array first :

```
let arr = [
{score:  6, text: "Spanish" color : "blue" },
{score:  8, text: "English" }
]

arr.forEach(function(item, index, theArray) {
  if(theArray[index].color == undefined){
      theArray[index].color = "red";
  }
});
```

Not tested but it should work!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.color = this.color || 'red';
    }
```